# How to appropriately flag questions for migration?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

I have recently flagged some questions for migration, e.g. [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248786/wlan0-component-not-present-in-my-kali-linux). It was migrated, but my flag was declined with the comment:

```
 I suggest migration to the Unix and Linux stackexchange. – jknappen 2 hours ago   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention
```

My question is: How should I mark a question for migration? I have not the priviledge for close votes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That was me. It's been so long since I didn't have the privilege to do things, that I sometimes forget that others can't do things. I was expecting people to vote to close (VTC). I keep feeling like I should get a sock-puppet account to stay in touch ...

Flags are really for things that require moderator attention to keep the community safe and at a level of quality. But in this case, because of the privilege issue, I should have migrated and not declined.

Comment: Users with ≥3000 rep can vote to close, but only moderators can migrate to [unix.se]. 3k users can only migrate to [so], [su] and [sf].

Comment: But 3k users can also generate a custom VTC option that could include any other SE site, it just won't migrate automatically.

Comment: No. 3k users can vote to close as off-topic and leave a comment through the same interface. The comment can say “this question belongs on Gardening.SE”. But that won't do anything to migrate the question. (It sometimes cause the asker to repost however, which is why such comments often cause more trouble than keeping the migration quiet until it happens.)

Comment: You just said what I said, I think ...

Comment: Does that mean users with <3k should not be flagging off-topic questions that would be on-topic for another community?

Comment: As someone who's a new member to the 3k club, if you flag as off topic and put a comment on the question like "this is better suited to XYZ community" that helps me understand why i'm voting to close a question and can expedite the process. However, mods have the final say if that's a good approach or not